# github user pages for my domain not working

Tags: github-pages

i have a domain `navyad.in` and i want to host some static pages for that domain on github.
I'm using User pages not the project pages on github.

What i did :

1). created a github repo called `navyad.github.io`.

2). under `master` branch of repo i have `index.html, CNAME, README.md` files.
In `CNAME` file i have my domain mentioned.

when  `navyad.github.io`is entered in browser, it takes me to the `navyad.in`. But the `index` file is **not displayed**. instead it is going to the page from where i have bought that domain [www.net4.in](http://www.net4.in).

what can be the issue ?.

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

That should mean that:

- You did follow the first part of the [GitHub help page on custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages): "[Setting the domain in your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#setting-the-domain-in-your-repo)", and GitHub does take you to your actual domain
- But you might *not* have completed the second step "[Setting up DNS](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#setting-up-dns)", which you should do in the [net4.in administration page](http://kb.net4.in/index.php/changingmanaging-domain-name-settings-for-customers/), setting up an `A record` pointing to 204.232.175.78.

Comment: 204.232.175.78 is that github server IP ?

Comment: @naveenyadav yes, as mentioned in https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working. More at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42272/setting-a-name-records-for-github-pages